# Index field is empty

Tags: indexing, lucene

I'm working with the Lucene library.  I want to index some documents and generate TermVectors for them.  I've written an Indexer class to create the fields of the index, but this code returns an empty field.

My index class is:

```
public class Indexer {

private static File sourceDirectory;
private static File indexDirectory;
private String fieldtitle,fieldbody;

public Indexer() {
    this.sourceDirectory = new File(LuceneConstants.dataDir);
    this.indexDirectory = new File(LuceneConstants.indexDir);
    fieldtitle = LuceneConstants.CONTENTS1;
    fieldbody= LuceneConstants.CONTENTS2;
}

public void index() throws CorruptIndexException,
        LockObtainFailedException, IOException {
    Directory dir = FSDirectory.open(indexDirectory.toPath());
    Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(StandardAnalyzer.STOP_WORDS_SET);  // using stop words
    IndexWriterConfig iwc = new IndexWriterConfig(analyzer);

    if (indexDirectory.exists()) {
        iwc.setOpenMode(IndexWriterConfig.OpenMode.CREATE);
    } else {
        // Add new documents to an existing index:
        iwc.setOpenMode(IndexWriterConfig.OpenMode.CREATE_OR_APPEND);
    }

    IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(dir, iwc);
    for (File f : sourceDirectory.listFiles()) {
        Document doc = new Document();
        String[] linetext=getAllText(f);
        String title=linetext[1];
        String body=linetext[2];

        doc.add(new Field(fieldtitle, title, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED, Field.TermVector.WITH_POSITIONS_OFFSETS));
        doc.add(new Field(fieldbody, body, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED, Field.TermVector.WITH_POSITIONS_OFFSETS));
        writer.addDocument(doc);
    }
    writer.close();
}

public String[] getAllText(File f) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    String textFileContent = "";
    String[] ar = null;

    try {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
    for (String str : Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(f.getAbsolutePath()))) {
         textFileContent += str;
            ar=textFileContent.split("--");

    }
    in.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("File Read Error");
}
    return ar;
}
}
```

and result of debug is:

```
doc     Document    #534    
fields  ArrayList   "size=0"    
Static          
linetext    String[]    #535(length=4)  
title   String          "how ...."  
body    String          "I created ...."
```

I also get another error in debugging:

> Non-static method "toString" cannot be referenced from a static context.

This error is happened for filepath.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you've got an empty file, or are running into an IOException.  See this part of your code:

```
String[] ar = null;

try {
    //Do Stuff
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("File Read Error");
}
return ar;
```

On an IOException, you fail to handle it, and effectively guarantee you'll immediately thereafter run into another exception.  You need to figure out how to handle it if you run into an IOException, or if `getAllText` returns an array of length 1 or 2

---

Also, not the issue you are currently running into, but this is almost certainly backwards:

```
if (indexDirectory.exists()) {
    iwc.setOpenMode(IndexWriterConfig.OpenMode.CREATE);
} else {
    // Add new documents to an existing index:
    iwc.setOpenMode(IndexWriterConfig.OpenMode.CREATE_OR_APPEND);
}
```

And there really isn't a need for it at all, anyway.  That's what `CREATE_OR_APPEND` is for, to write to an existing index, or create it if it isn't there.  Just replace that whole bit with

```
iwc.setOpenMode(IndexWriterConfig.OpenMode.CREATE_OR_APPEND);
```